# How to use onTap or onPressed in PopupMenuItem

Tags: flutter, dart

How can we implement use of `onTap` or `onPressed` in `PopupMenuItem`
Here is my code:

```
actions: <Widget>[
  PopupMenuButton(
    icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
    itemBuilder: (context) => [
      PopupMenuItem(
        child: Text("Settings"),
      ),
      PopupMenuItem(
        child: Text("Flutter.io"),
      ),
      PopupMenuItem(
        child: Text("Google.com"),
      ),
    ],
  ),
]
```

I want to navigate to SettingPage() on tapping or clicking Settings PopupMenuItem.
I am getting this error even after following a solution mentioned below and even after importing dart:js

```
Error: Not found: 'dart:js'
import 'dart:js';
```

Here are my dependencies:

```
import 'package:bfdi_app/Profile/editProfile.dart';
import 'package:bfdi_app/models/user.dart';
import 'package:bfdi_app/services/collection.dart';
import 'package:bfdi_app/settings.dart';
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:js';
```

Comment: You can wrap a menu item with InkWell widget

Comment: Thank you, but I want to navigate to SettingPage() on tapping or clicking Settings PopupMenuItem.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Just add this to your PopupMenuButton:

```
onSelected: (result) {
    if (result == 0) {
        Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SettingPage()),
        );
    }
},
```

And change your setting button to:

```
PopupMenuItem(
    child: Text("Settings"),
    value: 0,
),
```

Comment: I have done it but it is showing: Error: Not found: 'dart:js'. I have already imported dart:js

Comment: so put this: `import 'dart:js';` on the top of your file

Comment: I have already done it. I have updated the question, please look into it.

Comment: Add this line above your other imports. On the first line

Comment: In what platform do you build flutter?

Comment: Visual Studio Code

Comment: I mean web or mobile platform?

Comment: It is a mobile platform with AVM

Comment: Could you create another question with a detail description of your new issue?

Comment: Here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59479813/error-not-found-dartjs-import-dartjs

Answer (score 10):

There is a property called `onSelected`, you should use it, it handles `onTap` event.

```
PopupMenuButton(
  icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
  onSelected: (newValue) { // add this property
    setState(() {
      _value = newValue; // it gives the value which is selected
    });
  },
  itemBuilder: (context) => [
    PopupMenuItem(
      child: Text("Settings"),
      value: 0,
    ),
    PopupMenuItem(
      child: Text("Flutter.io"),
      value: 1,
    ),
    PopupMenuItem(
      child: Text("Google.com"),
      value: 2,
    ),
  ],
)
```

Comment: Hello, I want to navigate to SettingPage() on tapping or clicking Settings PopupMenuItem.

Answer (score 7):

I faced similar issues while navigating the screen using pop up menu button and I solve the issues by putting this method inside the onTap callback of PopupMenuItem:

```
    onTap: (){
WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) {
                            return ScreenName();
                          },
                        ),
                      );
                    });
}
```

Comment: Worked, thx! Strange though

Comment: It worked for me too! Still in confusion about the fact that it's normally working for everyone else without this extra piece of code, but not for me, why?

Answer (score 2):

There is now an [onTap() for PopupMenuItem](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/PopupMenuItem/onTap.html).

```
      PopupMenuButton(
        itemBuilder: (context) => [
          PopupMenuItem(
            child: Text("tap me"),
            onTap: () => print("TAP"),
          )
        ],
      ),
```

Answer (score 1):

-Edited based on comment-

That's it :

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  var items = [{'name':'Settings','value':0}, {'name':'Flutter.io','value':1}, {'name':'Google.com',,'value':2}];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
      child: PopupMenuButton(
              onSelected: (x) {
           if(x==0){
                Navigator.push(
                     context,
                     MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SettingPage()), );}
              },
              icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
              itemBuilder: (context) => items
                  .map<PopupMenuItem>((element) => PopupMenuItem(
                        child: Text(element['name]),
                        value: element['value'],
                      ))
                  .toList()),


    ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello, I want to navigate to SettingPage() on tapping or clicking Settings PopupMenuItem.

Comment: I have done it but it is showing: Error: Not found: 'dart:js'. I have already imported dart:js

Answer (score 1):

Callable value.

```
PopupMenuButton(
  icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
  onSelected: (value) {
    value();
  },
  itemBuilder: (context) => [
    PopupMenuItem(
      child: Text('Settings'),
      value: () {
        debugPrint('open Settings');
      },
    ),
    PopupMenuItem(
      child: Text('Flutter.io'),
      value: () {
        debugPrint('goto Flutter.io');
      },
    ),
  ],
)
```

Comment: This is a very clever solution. It avoids having to create a separate switch-case handler function to execute an action after a value was selected

Answer (score 0):

Use inheritance when showing popup with `showMenu(...)`

```
class PopupItem<T> extends PopupMenuItem<T> {

  final Function() onTap;

  PopupItem({this.onTap, Widget child, Key key})
      : super(child: child, key: key);

  @override
  _PopupItemState<T> createState() => _PopupItemState<T>();
}

class _PopupItemState<T> extends PopupMenuItemState<T, PopupItem<T>> {
  @override
  void handleTap() {
    widget.onTap?.call();
    super.handleTap();
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
  Widget _itemDelete() => PopupItem(
        onTap: () {
          // Handle tap here
        },
        child: Text(...)
      );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
onTap: (){

                  WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {

                      Navigator.push(

                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(

                          builder: (context)=>Page())): 

                          },
                        ),
                      );
                    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PopupMenuButton (
padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
icon:const Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down_outlined,color: Color.fromRGBO(34, 178, 232, 1)),
shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15.0))
),

```
                  onSelected: (x){
                    if (x=="Edit User") {
                      Get.to(EditUserPage());
                    }
                    else if(x=="Login History"){
                      Get.to(EditUserPage());
                    }
                    else if(x=="Change Password"){
                      Get.to(EditUserPage());
                    }
                    else if(x=="Deactivate User"){
                      Get.to(EditUserPage());
                    }
                  },
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) => <PopupMenuEntry >[
                    PopupMenuItem (
                      onTap: (){},
                      value:"Edit User",
                      child:  Row(
                        children: [
                          svgWedget(url:"assets/svg/edit.svg"),
                          SizedBox(width: 10,),
                          Text("Edit User"),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    PopupMenuItem (
                      onTap: ( )async{},
                      value:"Login History",
                      child:  Row(
                        children: [
                          svgWedget(url:"assets/svg/calendar.svg"),
                          SizedBox(width: 10,),
                          Text("Login History"),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    PopupMenuItem (
                      onTap: ()async{},
                      value:"Change Password",
                      child:  Row(
                        children: [
                          SvgPicture.asset("assets/svg/lock.svg",color: Color.fromRGBO(195, 172, 255, 1),),
                          SizedBox(width: 10,),
                          Text("Change Password"),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    PopupMenuItem (
                      onTap: ()async{},
                      value:"Deactivate User",
                      child:  Row(
                        children: [
                          svgWedget(url:"assets/svg/trash.svg"),
                          SizedBox(width: 10,),
                          Text("Deactivate User"),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ]
              ),
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).