# Error: Not found: 'dart:js' import 'dart:js';

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am creating a PopupMenuButton() in the AppBar section. 

This is my file:

```
import 'dart:js';
import 'package:bfdi_app/settings.dart';
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ProfilePage extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _ProfilePageState createState() => _ProfilePageState();
}

class _ProfilePageState extends State<ProfilePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          'App_Name',
          ),
        actions: <Widget>[
            PopupMenuButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
              onSelected:(value){
                if(value==0){
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>SettingPage())
                  );
                }
              },
              itemBuilder: (context) => [
                    PopupMenuItem(
                      child: Text("Settings"),
                      value:0,
               ],
            ),
          ],
       ),
      }
```

Now I am facing an error in Console Log:

```
Compiler message:
lib/Pages/addPost.dart:1:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:js'
import 'dart:js';
       ^
lib/Profile/profile.dart:1:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:js'
import 'dart:js';
       ^
```

I have already added the dependency dart:js, but still getting the same error.
Error:
[image]

Comment: Could you upload more information about this error? Could you upload your entire file? And error from the console?

Comment: Updated the error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: I have switched to the master channel and all working fine. Although I don't see any requirement of `dart.js` in your current code. so you can remove that too

---

ORIGINAL ANSWER:
I believe you are using `stable channel` so try to switch to `beta channel`.
Open your terminal and run,

```
$ flutter channel beta
```

Comment: I am currently in master channel.

Comment: I have switched to the master channel and all working fine. Although I don't see any requirement of dart.js in your current code. so you can remove that too.

Comment: Yup, I tried to remove it and it's working now, thank you.

Answer (score 17):

Go to your flutter installed directory/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/js-0.6.3-nullsafety.1/lib/js.dart

Delete or comment this line:

```
export 'dart:js' show allowInterop, allowInteropCaptureThis;
```

Then try again

Comment: You're a legend! Spent a good hour trying to clear caches, updating packages etc etc.

Comment: This will break web release versions btw.

Comment: This is not a robust solution. Cache directories are ephemeral.

Answer (score 7):

Sounds like an import issue as soon as you are trying to compile for a native application.

Try searching for and delte the incorrect dart:js import (`import 'dart:js';`).

Have a look at this [GitHub issue #70373](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/70373#issuecomment-883917719)

Answer (score 5):

I just del import 'package:js'. it works for me.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting [pub.dev](https://pub.dev/packages/js/install):

1. Depend on it
   Add this to your package's `pubspec.yaml` file:

   ```
   dependencies:
     js: ^0.6.2
   ```
2. Install it
   You can install packages from the command line:
   with `pub`:

   ```
   $ pub get
   ```

   with `flutter`:

   ```
   $ flutter pub get
   ```

   Alternatively, your editor might support pub get or flutter pub get. Check the docs for your editor to learn more.
3. Import it
   Now in your Dart code, you can use:

   ```
   import 'package:js/js.dart';
   ```

Answer (score 1):

in my case just flutter clean solved the issue

`flutter clean`

then

`flutter pub get`

Answer (score 1):

You may not running the app on supported platform by library. In my case I was running on Android which library just supported Web as output. No need to clear cache or comment some code.

Answer (score 1):

**Step -1**
Just remove dart:js

**Step -2**
Run on terminal  "flutter clean"

**Step -3**
Run on terminal "flutter pub get"

**Step -4**
Run your project

It will work

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this error when running a dart grpc project. I just ran `dart fix --apply` and this problem was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how it got there, but in one of my source code files, I had this import:

```
import 'dart:js_interop';
```

I removed it.

Also, I had to delete the **.dart_tool** folder in the root folder of my Flutter project, then re-built my project

Answer (score 0):

Try using the **js** package: https://pub.dev/packages/js#-installing-tab-

 You should try to use `package:js` instead of `dart:js`

Comment: I have added this `import 'package:js/js.dart';` and getting this error : `Compiler message:
/C:/Users/acer/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/js-0.6.1+1/lib/js.dart:8:1: Error: Not found: 'dart:js'
export 'dart:js' show allowInterop, allowInteropCaptureThis;
^`

Answer (score 0):

Actually mine was solved with just a system restart and a "flutter clean" command. (yes I am using beta channel) But weird thing was the files were existed already but the dependencies somehow couldn't read from the dart packages.

Answer (score 0):

This [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66370001/not-found-dartjs-export-dartjs-show-allowinterop-allowinteropcapturethi) allowed me to run tests using `dart:js` & without modifying my local flutter installation.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

check if you are not using that package in your project just remove unused packages.

Comment: should be a comment instead of answer