# "Not found: 'dart:js' export 'dart:js' show allowInterop, allowInteropCaptureThis" error when running tests

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web, flutter-test

In my Flutter app, I have a file called `web.dart` and inside it I have `webSaveAs` function which saves a file to my local machine in web.

```dart
@JS()
library main;

import 'package:js/js.dart';
import 'package:universal_html/html.dart';

/// Annotate `webSaveAs` to invoke JavaScript `window.webSaveAs`
@JS('webSaveAs')
external void webSaveAs(Blob blob, String fileName);
```

However, when I run any test (using `flutter test` command) which imports widgets where I have used `webSaveAs` function, I get the following error:

```sh
./../../../development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/js-0.6.3-nullsafety.3/lib/js.dart:8:1: Error: Not found: 'dart:js'
export 'dart:js' show allowInterop, allowInteropCaptureThis;
^
```

I am using `js: ^0.6.2` from https://pub.dev/packages/js and here is the result from `flutter doctor` command.

```sh
╰>>> flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, 1.25.0-8.3.pre, on macOS 11.2.1 20D74 darwin-x64, locale en-SG)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.5)
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2019.3.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.53.2)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!
```

Could someone help me figure this out? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Issue:

When you execute `flutter test` command, Flutter will compile the code in test files to native Dart and run inside a Dart VM where there is no Javascript support. Hence, it will not contain `dart:js`.

---

### Solution:

You can create a dummy file (let's say `web.test.dart`) like below to mock the functions that use `package:js` or `dart:js` package methods.

**`web.test.dart`**

```dart
import 'package:universal_html/html.dart';

void webSaveAs(Blob blob, String fileName) {
  // You can remove the below line below and include your own implementation if you need
  throw UnimplementedError();
}
```

And then create a new file (let's say `shared.dart`) like below.

**`shared.dart`**

```dart
export 'web.dart' if (dart.library.io) 'web.test.dart';
```

When you need to use `webSaveAs` function, instead of importing `web.dart` file, you should import `shared.dart`.

---

### Explanation:

`dart.library.io` is available in Dart VM and `dart.library.js` is available in web.

In web, `if (dart.library.io)` is `false`. Therefore, it will import `web.dart` which is what we want.

When running tests, `if (dart.library.io)` is `true` since the tests run in Dart VM. Hence, it will import `web.test.dart` which won't throw any errors since it does not import `package:js` or `dart:js`.

---

**References:**

- https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/36557
- https://medium.com/@dvargahali/dart-2-conditional-imports-update-16147a776aa8