# Flutter showDialog is not shown on PopupMenuItem tap

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using `PopupMenuButton` in my application. I want to `showDialog` on tapping a `PopupMenuItem`.

My `PopupMenuItem`:

```
PopupMenuItem(
    child: Text("Show dialog"),
    onTap: () { 
        showDialog(
            context: context,
            barrierColor: Colors.black26,
            builder: (context) => AlertDialog( 
            ...
        )
    },
),
```

Also using `onSelected` inside the `PopupMenuButton` didn't work.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Thats because onTap of popupMenuItem tries to use Navigator.pop to close the popup but at same time you are trying to show the dialog, So it closes the dialog and leaves the popup so, you can wait till the all the animations or ongoing things complete then show dialog

code: [dartPad code](https://dartpad.dev/?null_safety=true&id=653ee961795ce196691ca21c4189af9d)

```
 PopupMenuItem(
              child: const Text('Item 0'),
              onTap: () {
                WidgetsBinding?.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                  showCupertinoDialog(
                      context: context,
                      builder: (context) {
                        return CupertinoAlertDialog(
                          title: const Icon(CupertinoIcons.info_circle),
                          content: const Text(
                            'Hello User, Welcome',
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          ),
                          actions: [
                            CupertinoDialogAction(
                              isDefaultAction: true,
                              onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                              child: const Text('Thanks'),
                            ),
                          ],
                        );
                      });
                });
              }),
```

Comment: IMHO, this should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 9):

Try this one:

```dart
PopupMenuItem(
  child: Text("Show dialog"),
  onTap: () { 
      Future<void>.delayed(
        Duration.zero,
        () => showDialog(
              context: context,
              barrierColor: Colors.black26,
              builder: (context) => AlertDialog(...),
        ),
    ),
  },
);
```